# How to save IUImage and NSString which are generate by NSURL load from a XML file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios

i do this for writeToFile my XML file :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loadFlux];
        NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

        // Load XML data from web
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        // construct path within our documents directory
        NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = 
        [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"flux.xml"];
        // write to file atomically (using temp file)
        [data writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
        [prefs setValue:storePath forKey:@"CheminVersXML"];

        //Initialize the delegate.
        XMLToObjectParser *parser = [[XMLToObjectParser alloc] initXMLParser];

        //Set delegate
        [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

        //Start parsing the XML file.
        BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

        if(success)
            NSLog(@"No Errors");
        else
            NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

and to load i do this :

```
// Load XML data from file
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:storePath];
        // write to file atomically (using temp file)

        NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

        //Initialize the delegate.
        XMLToObjectParser *parser = [[XMLToObjectParser alloc] initXMLParser];

        //Set delegate
        [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

        //Start parsing the XML file.
        BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

        if(success)
            NSLog(@"No Errors");
        else
            NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

but i still have a probleme : my picture dont load (url) and my dynamic string too (guid).

[My XML file is here](http://recontv.fr/testXml.xml)

Thank you for your help

EDIT : how can i do offline, the first launching is online and i need to save all data for a probably offline launch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the NSXMLParserDelegate methods, at last you need to write

```
– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
– parser:parseErrorOccurred:
– parser:foundCharacters:
```

Please refer to documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate) and for an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example) or [here](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) to solve your ploblem, so yo will need to use NSURLConnection to retreive the image and url content. Cheers!

Comment: ok thanks but my problem is when i'm offline (online all works perfectly) i need to save the image and the dynamic string, but nothing happend, zones still blank... sorry if i forgot to mention that :s